# Remove x number of trailing character if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a ruby or rails function to remove any number of trailing `.` if it exists?

For example, these strings:

```
sample string
sample string.
sample string..
sample string...
```

Should all return:

`sample string`

But `sample... string...` should return `sample... string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "string......."
s.chomp(s[/\.+$/])
#=> "string"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

Comment: What a wicked way to do this :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>> str = "sample...string..."
>> str.gsub(/\.*$/, '')
=> "sample...string"
```

You can also use `gsub!` for inplace substitution

Comment: Two little flaws here: No need for a `gsub` here since there's only one end of line, `sub` is enough. And `$` is no good because it will match every newline on multiline strings, use `\z` instead to match the absolute string end. (FYI: The counterpart would be `\A` instead of `^`.)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's `String#[]` can work wonders. For example:

```
foo = 'sample string...'

foo[/\.+$/] = ''
foo # => "sample string"
```

And:

```
foo = 'sample... string...'
foo[/\.+$/] = ''
foo # => "sample... string"
```

That's fine for single strings. If you have text with multiple lines and want to change them all at once:

```
foo = "sample string
sample string.
sample string..
sample string...
sample... string..."

foo.gsub!(/\.+$/, '')
puts foo
# >> sample string
# >>     sample string
# >>     sample string
# >>     sample string
# >>     sample... string
```

What's important is that you're trying to remove the *last* `.` in the strings, so you need [an anchor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) to tell the regex engine what you're looking for. Look through the documentation to see what are available and how they affect your search/replace attempts.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "string......."
s.slice!(/\.+$/);s
#=> "string"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-slice

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "string......."
s.split(/\.+$/, 0).first
#=> "string"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split